# Using texture() in combination with JBox2D

Tags: textures, box2d, jbox2d

I'm getting some trouble using the `texture()` method inside `beginShape()/endShape()` clause.

In the `display()`-method of my class TowerElement (a bar which is `DYNAMIC`), I draw the object like following:

```
void display(){
    Vec2 pos = level.getLevel().getBodyPixelCoord(body);
    float a = body.getAngle(); // needed for rotation

    pushMatrix();

    translate(pos.x, pos.y);
    rotate(-a); 

    fill(temp);    // temp is a color defined in the constructor
    stroke(0);

    beginShape();
    vertex(-w/2,-h/2);
    vertex(w/2,-h/2);
    vertex(w/2,h-h/2);
    vertex(-w/2,h-h/2);
    endShape(CLOSE);

    popMatrix();

}
```

Now, according to the API, I can use the `texture()` method inside the shape definition. Now when I remove the `fill(temp)` and put `texture(img)` (img is a `PImage` defined in the constructor), the stroke gets drawn, but the bar isn't filled and I get the warning

> texture() is not available with this renderer

What can I do in order to use textures anyway? I don't even understand the error message, since I do not know much about different renderers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post this as an answer since I "reach the goal", but I don't know if it is good practice.

Instead of trying to attach a texture to a shape, I just draw an image(...) instead of a rect. In above code, before I tried to work with own shapes and texture, I simply had

```
void display(){
    //(...)
    rectMode(CENTER);
    pushMatrix();
    translate(pos.x, pos.y);
    rotate(-a);
    fill(temp);
    rect(0,0,w,h);
    popMatrix();
}
```

Now I tried to just remove `rectMode(CENTER)` and replacing `rect(0,0,w,h)` with

```
image(tex, -w/2, -h/2, w, h);
```

and it results in a "textured bar". Nevertheless I'm not sure if this is a good approach.